# How to avoid SQL update returns Row size too large

Tags: mysql, innodb

As I am trying to update a large table (on a online server as well as a MAMP installation) if get the message

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Row size too large (> 8126).

The table has 190 colums most of them small (`int` and `tinyint`) but also quite some `varchar(255)` due to installed translations and about 1000 rows. Splitting up to more tables is not an option as it belongs to a Joomla extension and as such updating would cause issues.

I searched for solutions and more info, but remain with questions:

If I change some columns to BLOB of TEXT (as suggested) **are there differences in approaching these columns?** What I mean to figure out if I can do this without interfering in the working of the extension.

Understand that setting

```
innodb_file_per_table=ON
innodb_default_row_format=dynamic
innodb_file_format=Barracuda
```

might help, but where do you check and change these settings? Where to find`my.cnf`?

In short, advice needed what is the best way to handle an issue like this?

Comment: @Your Common Sense Just read "duplicate" but still no clue about possible consequences of using BLOB or TEXT as well as where to find my.cnf . And that . . . where my questions. It is because I am struggling that I am here, not because I am a master . . .

Comment: John -- I added an Answer to that "dup" Question.  If it addresses your issue, good.  If you have one column per translations, it is a prime candidate for "not splaying an array across columns".  If my answer does not help enough, please start a new Question, including `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there may be other techniques.